# Symfony2.3 with xampp v3.2.1 files under web is not responding

Tags: php, windows, symfony, xampp

i have set up my symfony 2.3 project with xampp correctly as I had access the app_dev.php successfully. However, i can not access it and other files like config.php now!! I really have no idea what was going wrong, when I clicked on the web/ or type /path/to/web/app_dev.php all browsers are just keep loading, not even return errors.

p.s. preparations like "php app/check.php" has been done, and /web/config.php was also fine before I met this problem.

Please give some hints and I appreciate all! Thx..

Comment: which operating system are you using? did you try clearing your cache by running `php app/console cache:clear` or alternatively `rm -rf app/cache/*` ? What do you mean by "click" the files? have you set up any vhosts?

Comment: Also, post your `.htaccess` here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check for file permissions and turn on your error logger. Turn on display_errors and try it once again.

Possible reasons are 
- Permission to write in cache and log 
- Your symbolic links is not pointing properly to web 
- Config file is not configured with ORM etc..

All these should come as error file and will be shown on the screen